# Save a h2o.ai model to S3 bucket in python

Tags: h2o

I have been using the command below to save my h2O model into a s3 bucket in python3 (I am using amazon EMR):

```
h2o.save_model(model=best_gbm1,path='s3://bucketname/folder1/folder2', force=False)
```

but I do get the following error:

> H2OServerError: HTTP 500 Server Error:
>   Server error java.lang.RuntimeException:
>     Error: Not implemented
>     Request: None

Do you know if it is possible to save a H2O model directly to a S3 bucket?

Comment: version information here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to save an h2o-3 model to s3 via the `save_model()` is not currently supported (as of version 3.22.1.6).

Comment: I am a bit confused here, I get the same error as OP, however in doc it clearly states s3 for [save_models()](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?highlight=save_model#h2o.save_model). Is it an error in the documentation? Thanks

Comment: @Joesmaker please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem in version 3.26.0.6 and solved it by changing the protocol to s3a instead of s3:

```
h2o.save_model(model=best_gbm1,path='s3a://bucketname/folder1/folder2', force=False)
```

I.e. use the object-based S3 overlay instead of the block-based one.